# I have problem using preload function to load images with react-p5 library

Tags: reactjs, p5.js, preload

I have used react-p5 library to integrate the P5 library with React but when I use the preload function to load images it gives me and error. The question is, how do I get the preload p5 function to work with loading images in React?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";
import ReactJS from './images/Icons/React.jpg';
let test;
export default class Sket extends Component {
  x = 50
  y = 50

  preload = (p5) =>{
     test = p5.loadImage(ReactJS, ()=>{
        p5.image(test, 0, 0, 50, 50)
     });
  }

  setup = (p5, parent) => { // window width is still not optimized for extra large screen
    var sket = p5.createCanvas(parent.offsetWidth, parent.offsetWidth).parent(parent);
    sket.position(0, 0);
  }
  draw = (p5) => {
    p5.background(0)
    p5.ellipse(this.x, this.y, 70, 70)
    this.x++
    this.y++
  //  p5.image(test, 50, 50)
  }

  render() {
    return <Sketch setup={this.setup} draw={this.draw} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `preload` at all? `loadImage()` already has a callback. And on a syntax note, why are you assigning properties instead of declaring class functions? Just use `preload(p5) { ... }` , `setup(p5, parent) { ... }` etc.

Comment: Good points, I will do that instead. Thanks.

Comment: just remember that `loadImage` gets you "the image you need", so you want to assign that to a variable that you already have sitting around for that purpose (e.g. global `let myImg;` and then trigger a redraw, with your draw function having a line like `if (myImg) p5.image(myImg)`

Comment: I tried that bro but still the image is not displayed. Please do you mind to show me the code that will get me to load the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your image from URL, not "from a variable", so:

```
export default class Sketch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // just keep these in your constructor:
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
  } 

  setup(p5, parent) {
    this.p5 = p5;
    p5.loadImage("./images/blah.jpg", img => {
      this.img = img;
      p5.redraw(); // <- only if you're running with noLoop()
    });
  }

  ...
```

and then with draw updated to draw your image only if and when it exists:

```
draw() {
  const { p5, img, x, y } = this;

  if (img) {
    p5.image(img, x, y);
  }

  ...
}
```

And of course: you can't just say `<Sketch setup={this.setup} draw={this.draw}>` because the `this` keyword will be pointing at the global scope by the time that runs. Ever since React 16, you either need to use `bind` in the constructor to explicitly shadow your functions (which is a terrible idea), or use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make sure that `this` points to what it is at declare time.

Arrow functions are by far the better choice:

```
render() {
  return <Sketch
    setup={(...args) => this.setup(...args)}
    draw={() => this.draw()}
  />;
}
```

Comment: Well done my man, it worked after I changed ps to p5 and in render I added "/" at the end of <Sketch> component. I have used p5 with JS but this type of code was new to me with React library. Again, thank you very much <3.

Comment: Thank you both for this detailed analysis. In my case, I was getting an error when referencing the image directly thru a path name/ URL. However, I went back and updated it to a variable like in the original question and it works perfectly. Thanks again!